# Unable to equate id's of two object in nodejs to the objects returned from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Here is the code snipped which runs when I open a webpage from browser, it queries all the users, and just removes the users object who is querying it.

I am trying to do it by equating their `_id`'s field which is generated by default in mongodb and is always unique, I am able to print each object's `_id` field but when i try it in **if** condition it fails to enter the if condition,

```
user.find({}, { 'local.name': 1, route_id: 1, stop_number: 1, _id: 1 }, function (err, allusers) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var len = allusers.length;
    for (var index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        console.log(allusers[index]._id);
        console.log(index);
        if (allusers[index]._id === req.user._id) {
            console.log("here");
            allusers.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    res.send(allusers);
})
```

Here is the output of above:

```
GET /javascripts/delete_user.js 304 1ms
588f2aded1902a1b08959145 
0  
58bd116c84fdb70a9c4f34aa 
1
```

can't figure where I am going wrong, and yes, **`req.user._id`** equals to the first user's id i.e. `588f2aded1902a1b08959145`, still does not enters if condition, if someone can please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I guess you are comparing two `id's` which are same, but it prints unequal??? or ??

Comment: It fails to enter if condition while comparing the id's of two object, but enters the if condition if I add .toString() method and servers crashes with error `events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined at C:\Users\shjain\WebstormProjects\route_manager\routes.js:325‌​:44 Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: are the both ids from the mongodb or is anyone of them in enetered from client having datatype string

Comment: both id were created by mongodb by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the error, I was removing the object as soon as I found it, which was reducing the length of allusers array and when it will try to reach last index which is now undefined as I spliced it already it was reading the -id property of undefined.

Here is the correct code:

```
user.find({}, { 'local.name': 1, route_id: 1, stop_number: 1, _id: 1 }, function (err, allusers) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var len = allusers.length;
    var to_remove;
    for (var index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        if (allusers[index]._id === req.user._id) {
            to_remove = index;
        }
    }
    allusers.splice(to_remove, 1);
    res.send(allusers);
})
```

Comment: does it enters inside `if (allusers[index]._id === req.user._id)`  condition

Comment: yes, it enters now, maybe it was entering before as well but the error came before and server crashed therefore i was unable to see the "here" in console
embarrassing amateur mistake.

Comment: you said `It fails to enter if condition while comparing the id's of two object` so i provided the lodash deep comparison ??????????, but now it enters,, ??????

Comment: not saying it now enters, I am saying maybe it was entering but since here was not printing I thought It was not. should have checked it thoroughly before

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if( allusers[index]._id.toString() === req.user._id.toString() ) {
                            console.log("here");
                            allusers.splice(index,1);
                        }
```

Works for me :)

Comment: yes, it enters the if loop now but throws error and servers crashes, 
`here
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at C:\Users\shjain\WebstormProjects\route_manager\routes.js:325:44

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: even I tried .toString(), before but for some wierd reason it now fails to read the id of the object, any ideas ? ?

Comment: Either allusers[index] or req.user does not have the _id field

Comment: as I mentioned, both of them have id object and I am able to print id of all of them.